# Move an element in the array row-wise and shifting the others?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am working with numpy arrays and and I would like to move a certain value located at certain index by 2 positions on the right while shifting the others element involved on the left by one position each. To be more precise, here below is what I would like to achieve:

from:

```
     start = [0., 1., 2.],
             [0., 0., 0.],
             [5., 0., 1.]
```

to:

```
       end = [1., 2., 0.],
             [0., 0., 0.],
             [5., 0., 1.]
```

As you can see from the first row, 0 has been moved by two position on the right and 1 and 2 by one position on the left. So far, I succeded by moving an element by one position and moving the other by defining:

```
def right_move(arr, index, n_steps:int):


   row = index[0]
   col = index[1]

   try:
       arr[row,col], arr[row, col + n_steps] = arr[row, col + n_steps], arr[row, col]

   except:
       pass

   return arr
```

where n_steps=1. If I input n_steps=2, it won't work since the element in the middle of the swapping remain unchanged.

Can someone help me? Other easier solution are more then welcome!

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you need numpy.roll check it out https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0., 1., 2.],
                [0., 0., 0.],
                [5., 0., 1.]])
arr[0] = np.roll(arr[0], 2)
arr
# output:
# [[1., 2., 0.],
#  [0., 0., 0.],
#  [5., 0., 1.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed the functionality of `np.roll`. However, `np.roll` doesn't allow roll on individual row. It piqued my interest to implement a function using `as_strided` to extend this functionality to `np.roll`

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def custom_roll(arr, r_tup):
    m = np.asarray(r_tup)
    arr_roll = arr[:, [*range(arr.shape[1]),*range(arr.shape[1]-1)]].copy() #need `copy`
    strd_0, strd_1 = arr_roll.strides
    n = arr.shape[1]
    result = as_strided(arr_roll, (*arr.shape, n), (strd_0 ,strd_1, strd_1))

    return result[np.arange(arr.shape[0]), (n-m)%n]
```

Just passing a tuple indicate number of steps for each row. In your case, it rolls only row `0` either `2` positions forward or `-1` position backward. so the tuple is `(2,0,0)` or `(-1,0,0)`

```
start = np.array([[0., 1., 2.],
                  [0., 0., 0.],
                  [5., 0., 1.])

out = custom_roll(start, (2,0,0))

Out[780]:
array([[1., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 0., 1.]])
```

Or

```
out = custom_roll(start, (-1,0,0))

Out[782]:
array([[1., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 0., 1.]])
```

---

Roll first and last row: `(2,0,2)`

```
out =  custom_roll(start, (2,0,2))

Out[784]:
array([[1., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 5.]])
```